# Python get audio data from rtsp stream

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am trying to get audio data from an rstp stream that is in the format of mlaw with Python 3.7. I want to be able to place it in a numpy array like I can do with pyaudio. Then when there is sound, record it. It isn't something that always has audio noise.

This is how I coded it for Pyaudio using a physical input. Basically I want to do the same, but instead use an RTSP stream from a URL.

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = self.p.open(format=FORMAT,
                     channels=CHANNELS,
                     rate=RATE,
                     input=True,
                     output=True,
                     frames_per_buffer=chunk)

def listen(self):
  print('Listening beginning')
  while True:
      input = self.stream.read(chunk)
      rms_val = self.rms(input)
      if rms_val > Threshold:
          record()

def record():
    print('Noise detected, recording beginning')
    rec = []
    rec_start = time.time()
    current = time.time()
    end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH

    while current <= end:

        data = self.stream.read(chunk)
        if rms(data) >= Threshold: end = time.time() + 2

        current = time.time()
        rec.append(data)

def rms(frame):
    count = len(frame) / swidth
    format = "%dh" % (count)
    shorts = struct.unpack(format, frame)
    sum_squares = 0.0
    for sample in shorts:
        n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
        sum_squares += n * n
    rms = math.pow(sum_squares / count, 0.5)
    return rms * 1000
```

Here is what I have tried for ffmpeg, but it just freezes with no error and doesn't print any data. It even actually crashes the IoT device with the rtsp stream on it. Is there a way i can do this with urllib or requests or even an ffmpeg command opened with subprocess?

```
import ffmpeg

packet_size = 4096

process = ffmpeg.input('rtsp://192.168.1.122:554/au:scanner.au').output('-', format='mulaw').run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
packet = process.stdout.read(packet_size)

while process.poll() is None:
    packet = process.stdout.read(packet_size)
    print(packet)
```

My end result is doing two things. One recording a wav when there is audio, Two, converting from the recorded wav and uploading that audio to SFTP as opus and mp3.

Comment: Hey Dude, did you get more results on this? I'm also trying to find something that can accept rtsp and pass to pyaudio. thanks for anything! @smashedbotatos